# "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" when deleting image

Tags: python, windows, image

So I have some code where I go through a bunch of images to see whether they have the right size, or is corrupt. I do this with the following code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

    try:
        img = Image.open("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, n))
    except:
        os.remove("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, n))
        continue

    if img.size[0] < 600:
        img.close()
        os.remove("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, n))
    elif img.size[0] > 600:
        img.close()
        break
```

This is within a loop of course (as the n indicates).

So the first try/except code it tries to open a file, and if it can it moves on. If it cannot it is usually corrupt, and I ask it to delete that file. So far so good. I then ask it to check if the image has the right size, and if not, delete it. However, this is pretty much where it goes wrong every time, and I end up with the error as posted in the title.

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
```

And it is kind of random. Sometimes I get it within the first 10-20 images, and sometimes it happens at image 300 or something. My idea is that the image has to be open, and therefore cannot be deleted. But as you can see I have used the img.close() function just before, so this shouldn't happen imo. So is there anyway to fix this ? Do I have to put in a time delay so it actually has time to close the image before trying to delete it, or...?

Comment: The image is most likely open in another program. `img.close()` is not working asynchronously: it should not return until the file is really closed.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but doesn't an exception mean that `img` refers to a previous file if you do this in a loop? Then `img` and `n` get out of sync.

Comment: I have checked and restarted my computer several times. There are no other programs that should be running or have opened the image when the error comes up...

Comment: Are you running an antivirus?

Comment: The problem might be in `Image.open` and `img.close`. I would first experiment with a regular file `open`.

Answer (score 3):

My wild guess that it has something to do with Windows files system. Adding a retry loop with a short sleep should solve this issue.

```
def remove_file(path, retries=3, sleep=0.1):
    for i in range(retries):
        try:
            os.remove(path)
        except WindowsError:
            time.sleep(sleep)
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find which process has the file open by catching the exception, entering the debugger, and then using Processs Explorer:

```
try:
    ...
except WindowsError:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Process Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer
(Ctrl-F, find handle or dll)