# Deleting a file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code takes a list of file and folder paths, loops through them, then uploads to a Google Drive. If the path given is a directory, the code creates a .zip file before uploading. Once the upload is complete, I need the code to delete the .zip file that was created but the deletion throws an error: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Temp\Newfolder.zip'. The `file_path` being given is C:\Temp\Newfolder. From what I can tell the only process using the file is this script but `with open(...)` should be closing the file when the processing is complete. Looking for suggestions on what could be done differently.

```
import os
import zipfile
import time

def add_list(filePathList, filePath): 
    filePathList.append(filePath) 
    return filePathList

def deleteFiles(filePaths):
    for path in filePaths:
        os.remove(path)

for file_path in file_paths:
    if os.path.isdir(file_path) and not os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]:
        # Compress the folder into a .zip file
        folder_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        zip_file_path = os.path.join('C:\\Temp', folder_name + '.zip')
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_file:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
                for filename in files:
                    file_to_zip = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    zip_file.write(file_to_zip, os.path.relpath(file_to_zip, file_path))
            zip_file.close()

        # Update the file path to the zipped file
        file_path = zip_file_path

    
    # Create request body
    request_body = {
        'name': os.path.basename(file_path),
        'mimeType': 'application/zip' if file_path.endswith('.zip') else 'text/plain',
        'parents': [parent_id],
        'supportsAllDrives': True
    }

    #Open the file and execute the request
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        media_file = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='application/zip' if file_path.endswith('.zip') else 'text/plain')
        upload_file = service.files().create(body=request_body, media_body=media_file, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()

        # Print the response
        print(upload_file)
    

    if file_path.endswith('.zip'):
        add_list(filePathList, file_path)
    
time.sleep(10)
deleteFiles(filePathList)
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446888/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process), it seems like you might have to try remvoing the file a few times before the operating system will let you delete the file

Answer (score 0):

You're using `with` statements to properly close the open files, but you're not actually *using* the open files, just passing the path to another API that is presumably opening the file for you under the hood. Check the documentation for the APIs here:

```
    media_file = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='application/zip' if file_path.endswith('.zip') else 'text/plain')
    upload_file = service.files().create(body=request_body, media_body=media_file, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

to figure out if `MediaFileUpload` objects, or the various things done with `.create`/`.execute` that uses it, provides some mechanism for ensuring deterministic resource cleanup (as is, if `MediaFileUpload` opens the file, and nothing inside `.create`/`.execute` explicitly closes it, at least one such file is *guaranteed* to be open when you try to remove them at the end, possibly more than one if reference cycles are involved or you're on an alternate Python interpreter, causing the problem you see on Windows systems). I can't say what might or might not be required, because you don't show the implementation, or specify the package it comes from.

Even if you are careful not to hold open handles yourself, [there are cases where other processes can lock it, and you need to retry a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45446888/364696) (virus scanners can cause this issue by attempting to scan the file as you're deleting it; I believe properly implemented there'd be no problem, but they're software written by humans, and therefore some of them will misbehave). It's particularly common for files that are freshly created (virus scanners being innately suspicious of any new file, especially compressed files), and as it happens, you're creating fresh zip files and deleting them in short order, so you may be stuck retrying a few times.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to fix:

1. Go to your folder where is python installed. Expl.: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
2. Choose with right click the python.exe --> properties --> copatibility --> execute as admin --> ok
3. Restart your computer
4. Run this python code again --> it works as you like